# Append dict items to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have a dict which consists

```
docs[infile]={'tf':{}, 'idf':{},'words':[], 'tf_idf':{}}
```

and I have a list that I want to pass some of the dict's items

the sub-dicts tf_idf AND idf contain data such as {(word, number),(word, number),...}

I need to store in the list both tf_idf and idf items. This code stores only one of those 2 sub-dicts.

```
templist=[]
for key in docs: #stores data in separate list
    TF_IDF_buffer = docs[key]['tf_idf'].items()
    templist.append(TF_IDF_buffer)
```

Is it possible to store both of them in the list ?

Comment: What should happen if they have common keys? Should only one value be kept or both?

Comment: keys are consisting of words and numbers. words are same but the numbers are not. I dont have an issue if i store twice the words .

Comment: so templist will be list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This joins the two sequences of items, keeping duplicated keys:

```
templist=[]
for key, value in docs.items():
    tf_idf = list(value['tf_idf'].items())
    idf = list(value['idf'].items())
    templist.append(tf_idf + idf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should be what you are looking for

```
templist=[]
for key in docs: #stores data in separate list
    for word in docs[key]['words']:
         idf = docs[key]['idf']
         tf_idf = docs[key]['tf_idf']
         temp_list.append((word, tf_idf, idf))
```

However, I also saw some of your other questions on this forum. I think your structure of nested lists and dicts is somewhat complicated. For instance, your list of words, is duplicated by the keys in `idf` and `tf_idf`.

You may want to consider using a more Object Oriented approach.

You could define a class like this:

```
class Document:
     def __init__(self, words, idf, tf_idf):
         self.words = words
         self.idf = idf
         self.tf_idf = tf_idf
```

Also, from my memory of using NLP, I remember that using `collections.defaultdict` can be quite useful (especially if your `idf` and `tf_idf` dictionaries are sparse).

Comment: the line temp_list.append((word, tf_idf, idf)) is causing overflow . results in file [('from', {'all': -0.0022909517465558244, 'help': -0.0022909517465558244,... ] . I think it takes for each word and creates a subdict. i got a file 1GB+ in less than a minute.

Comment: It was just a hint.

Suppose you keep track of counts of words in documents using a `dict`. If a word does _not_ appear in a document, you will need to store dict[word] = 0.  If you use `defaultdict(int)`, then if a word is not found in a document, it will be zero automatically.

You can also store probabilities in a defaultdict. So if a word, does not appear in a document, e.g `defaultdict(lambda: -float('Inf'))`.